# In libuv framework, when using two call back functions, why they affect each other

Tags: c++, libuv

In some practices, I found when I use two handlers, for example, a uv_timer with an uv_idle of libuv, they may act not as I expected. I wrote a similar toy example here:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <uv.h>

uv_idle_t idle;
uv_loop_t *loop;
uv_timer_t timer;

void cb2(uv_timer_t *handler)
{
    printf("bbb\n");
    sleep(1);
}

void cb(uv_idle_t *handler)
{
    printf("aaa\n");
    sleep(5);
    // while(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    loop = new uv_loop_t;
    uv_loop_init(loop);
    uv_idle_init(loop, &idle);
    uv_timer_init(loop, &timer);
    uv_timer_start(&timer, cb2, 5, 1000);
    uv_idle_start(&idle, cb);

    // uv_idle_stop(&idle);
    printf("Now quitting.\n");
    uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
    while (1)
    {
        ;
    }
    uv_loop_close(loop);
    free(loop);
    return 0;
}
```

I ran it under linux. I want the timer run **cb2** repeatly every 1000ms, at the same time, another idle function **cb** is also runing.   They should be two irrelevant threads that do their own thing separatly. So I expect that they print the "aaa" for every about 2 seconds and print "bbb" for every 5 seconds.

However the fact is when I start them simultaneously, the "aaa" will choke the "bbb" output. a "bbb" only printed after an "aaa" printed. That is confused, because I though the framework is asychronous.

Why do these happen? and how should I use it properly? Thank you!

Comment: From the [documentation](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html#the-i-o-loop): `"The I/O (or event) loop is the central part of libuv. It establishes the content for all I/O operations, and it’s meant to be tied to a single thread. One can run multiple event loops as long as each runs in a different thread"`.  So your assumption that the callbacks will be invoked on independent threads is incorrect and the calls to `sleep(...)` will block any pending operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> print the "aaa" for every about 2 seconds and print "bbb" for every 5 seconds

You set the timer to fire repeatedly every `1000 ms`:

```
uv_timer_start(&timer, cb2, 5, 1000);
```

You can't expect it to fire every 2 seconds when setting the timer to fire repeatedly every second.

Regarding the `uv_idle_t` handle:

> Despite the name, idle handles will get their callbacks called on every loop iteration, not when the loop is actually “idle”.

Then there's this:

```
loop = new uv_loop_t;
// ...
free(loop);
```

Never do this. If you create something with `new` you should `delete` it when done time it. You don't have to create it dyncamically here though, so just create an automatic variable.

If you want two timed events, make them both so:

```
#include <uv.h>

#include <cstdio>

void cb2(uv_timer_t* handler) {
    std::puts("bbb");
}

void cb(uv_timer_t* handler) {
    std::puts("aaa");
}

int main() {
    uv_loop_t loop;
    uv_loop_init(&loop);

    uv_timer_t timer_1;
    uv_timer_init(&loop, &timer_1);
    uv_timer_start(&timer_1, cb2, 0, 1000);

    uv_timer_t timer_5;
    uv_timer_init(&loop, &timer_5);
    uv_timer_start(&timer_5, cb, 0, 5000);

    uv_run(&loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

    uv_loop_close(&loop);
}
```

Note that `uv_loop_close` will never be reached since there's nothing shutting down the event loop.